# Java POJO: strategies for handling a queue of request objects to a server

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, pool, pojo

Right now I'm torn up in deciding the best way of handling request objects that I send up to a server. In other words, I have tracking request objects for things such as impression and click tracking within my app. Simple requests with very low payloads. There are places in my app where said objects that need to be tracked appear concurrently next to each other (at most three concurrent objects that I have to track), so every time said objects are visible for example, I have to create a tracking request object for each of them.

Now I already know that I can easily create a singleton queue thread which adds those objects into a vector and my thread either processes them in the main loop or calls wait on the queue until we have objects to process. While this sounds like a clear cut solution, the queue can accumulate into the dozens, which can be cumbersome at times, since it's making one connection for each request, thus it won't run concurrently.

What I had in mind was to create a thread pool which would allow me to create up two concurrent connections via semaphore and process thread objects that would contain my tracking event requests. In other words, I wanted to create a function that would create a new thread Object and add it into a Vector, in which the thread pool would iterate through the set of threads and process them two at a time. I know I can create a function that would add objects like so:

```
public boolean addThread(Runnable r){
synchronized(_queue){
    while(!dead){
       _queue.addElement(r);
       //TODO: How would I notify my thread pool object to iterate through the list to process the queue? Do I call notify on the queue object, but that would only work on a thread right??
       return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I am wondering is how will the threads themselves get executed. How can I write a function that would execute the thread pool after adding a thread to the list? Also, since the semaphore will block after the second connection, will that lock up my app until there is an open slot, or will it just lock up in the thread pool object while looping through the list?

As always, since I am targeting a J2ME/Blackberry environment, only pre-1.5 answers will be accepted, so no Generics or any class from the Concurrent package.

EDIT: So I take it that this is what it should look like more or less:

```
class MyThreadPool extends Thread{

  private final Vector _queue = new Vector();
  private CappedSemaphore _sem;
  public MyWaitingThread (){
      _sem = new CappedSemaphore(2);
      this.start();
  }
  public void run(){
     while(!dead){
        Runnable r = null;
        synchronized(_queue){
          if(_queue.isEmpty()){
            _queue.wait();
          } else {
            r = _queue.elementAt(0);
            _queue.removeElement(0);
          }
       }
       if(r != null){
          _sem.take();
          r.run();
          _sem.release();
       }
    }
 }
 public boolean addThread(Runnable r){
   synchronized(_queue){
   if(!dead){
     _queue.addElement(r);
     _queue.notifyAll();
     return true
   }
   return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be so quick to discount the Java 5 concurrency package. There's wasn't anything magical in Java 5 that enabled it, much of it was done by Doug Lea in Java 1.4, it was just standardized in Java 5. http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/index.php is a backport of j.u.concurrent.

Comment: Since the implementation of Semaphore implements Serializable (something that doesn't exist in MIDP/CLDC), I can't simply import the class nilly-willy, hence the reason I'm aiming for a POJO solution, something that can be accomplished on primitive and bare-bones objects alone.

Comment: It all looks good with one thought.  If you ensure that there will always be two threads started you wouldnt need the semaphore.  You are confining the concurrency to thread locality so you need not worry about another synchronization primitive.  Otherwise what you have should work.

Comment: I'm just curious how I can do that without the use of a semaphore, since it looks like the way it's written, it will only process them consecutively, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

What you would want to do, in on the thread side have the each thread wait on the queue. For example

```
class MyWaitingThread extends Thread{

   private final Queue _queue;
   public MyWaitingThread (Queue _queue){
      this._queue = _queue;
   }
   public void run(){
      while(true){
       Runnable r = null;
       synchronized(_queue){
            if(_queue.isEmpty())
                _queue.wait();
            else
               r = queue.pop();
        }
      if(r != null) r.run();
      }
   }
}
```

And in your other logic it would look like:

```
public void addThread(Runnable r){
     if(!dead){
       synchronized(_queue){
         _queue.addElement(r);
         _queue.notifyAll();
       }
     }
}
```

That `_queue.notifyAll` will wake up all threads waiting on the `_queue` instance.  Also, notice I moved the `while(!dead)` outside of the synchronized block and changed it to `if(!dead)`.  I can imagine keeping it the way you originally had it wouldnt have worked exactly like you hoped.

Comment: I guess I forgot to edit the function to return a boolean, that way it can escape the while loop, since this is how Sun did it for their simple queue example in the J2ME threading tutorial. I'll go fix that now. Also, I can't use the Queue object since it won't work on J2ME, but I see what you are implying. I have to call elementAt and then removeElement so that i pluck out my object from my Vector queue.